# Problema con Turbolink en ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy armando un panel de administración y en mi navegación tengo los clásicos botones de minimizar la barra de navegación y el dropdown por cada accion que tenga una subaccion y todo funciona en un inicio pero me desplazo por otros modulos digamos me voy a almacen al registrar un nuevo producto se me va el js no funciona los botones ni el dropdown se me paso algo? debo anhadir algo? gracias de antemano.

Cada vez que me desplazo de modulos es como si se fueran todos los JS pero al actualizar la pagina los JS vuelven tambien eh notado que sucede esto cuando me voy a un link vacio esos que tienen en el hfref = "#"

Comment: Agrega código a tu pregunta de lo que has hecho, si no, no hay como adivinar.

Comment: Si deseas que te ayudemos tu debes proveer un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando *jQuery*, asegúrate de tener el siguiente código:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // código
});
```